# SeleniumBasic: VBA Webscrape FindElementByXPath grabs Class from the wrong tr block

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

My code scrapes the highlighted texts from here (see the code for the details of the website):
[image: Farnell]

My code cycles through all three `ProductRows` to grab the appropriate `MPN`, `Supplier_ID`, `QTY_InStock` & `Pkg Option`.
But what happens is the code does the first Product Row fine, then from the second row on **it always returns `Pkg Option` of the First Row for both Row 2 & 3**. Results are given by the `MsgBox()` at the end.

**But why does it do that???
All the other attributes collected are the appropriate ones to the actual row.**

The mistake happens at:

```
Prod_Pkg = Trim(ProductRow.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='attachmentText cuttapePara']").text)
```

...in here:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    Dim driver As WebDriver
    Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    driver.Start
    driver.Get ("https://uk.farnell.com")
    
    Dim Component_To_Find As String
    Component_To_Find = "C5750X7R2E105K230KA"   ' MPN - Manufacturer Part Number of a component
    
    Dim Farnell_Search_Box As WebElement
    Dim Farnell_Search_Button As WebElement
    
    Dim KeyPad As Selenium.keys
    Set KeyPad = New Selenium.keys
    
    Set Farnell_Search_Box = driver.FindElementByName("st")
    Set Farnell_Search_Button = driver.FindElementById("searchMain")
    
    Farnell_Search_Box.SendKeys (Component_To_Find)
    Farnell_Search_Button.submit
    
    Dim ProdList As WebElements
    Dim ProductRow As WebElement
    Dim InStock As String
    Dim Prod_Row_Comp_Name As String
    Dim Prod_Pkg As String
    Dim Supplier_ID As String
    'Dim Comp_Name As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    'On Error Resume Next
    Set ProdList = driver.FindElementById("sProdList").FindElementByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")
    'On Error GoTo 0
    If Not ProdList Is Nothing Then
        'For Each ProductRow In ProdList
        For i = 1 To ProdList.Count
            Set ProductRow = ProdList(i)
            
            'On Error Resume Next
            Prod_Row_Comp_Name = Trim(ProductRow.FindElementByTag("a").text)                                    ' Get MPN
            Prod_Pkg = Trim(ProductRow.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='attachmentText cuttapePara']").text)     ' Get Packaging Option
            InStock = ProductRow.FindElementByClass("availability").FindElementByClass("inStockBold").text      ' Get QTY In Stock
            Supplier_ID = ProductRow.FindElementByClass("sku", -1, True).text                                   ' Get Supplier ID of Component
            'On Error GoTo 0
            
            MsgBox ("ProductRow:" & vbTab & i & vbCrLf & _
                    "MPN:" & vbTab & vbTab & Prod_Row_Comp_Name & vbCrLf & _
                    "Pkg:" & vbTab & vbTab & Prod_Pkg & vbCrLf & _
                    "QTY_InStock:" & vbTab & InStock & vbCrLf & _
                    "Supp_ID:" & vbTab & vbTab & Supplier_ID)
            
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT 1**
With some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77474505/selenium-vba-get-parent-webelement-of-a-child-webelement), I have tried a different method to get the WebElement of the failing readout.

By replacing this line:

```
Prod_Pkg = Trim(ProductRow.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='attachmentText cuttapePara']").text)     ' Get Packaging Option
```

With this one:

```
Prod_Pkg = Trim(ProductRow.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='pfIcon pfPackOptIcon_TC']//parent::div").text)     ' Get Packaging Option
```

It still doesn't read the appropriate `Pkg Option` to the actual `ProductRow` (Row 2 & 3). Row 2 & 3 always return the data from Row 1, which is "Cut Tape".

**Edit 2**

I have also tried this, from the [same page as the above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77474505/selenium-vba-get-parent-webelement-of-a-child-webelement), an answer by someone else of how to get the parent of a WebElement:

```
Prod_Pkg = ProductRow.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='pfIcon pfPackOptIcon_TC']").FindElementByXPath("..").text     ' Get Packaging Option
```

Still not working as expected.

Comment: remove the `On Error Resume Next` and check if there is any error happening. Note that in case of an error, you don't overwrite the content of the variables, so they keep their values.

Comment: thanks for the comment.. it is commented out as you can see above. I tested it with `On Error` removed,  before I posted my problem, to make sure it wasn't anything obvious. thanks again

Comment: with all 4 of the `On Error` lines commented out, I am not getting any errors, but the code grabs the `class='attachmentText cuttapePara'` tag of `ProductRow 1` for all other `ProductRows` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot really answer why `FindElementByXPath` finds the first entry of the whole page instead of only the table row. It's hard to find any documentation about that, the examples I found always use the command only on page level.

However what works is to use `FindElementByClass` or `FindElementsByClass`. I prefer to use `FindElementsByClass` even if there is only one matching element - simply because it returns an empty list if no element was found while `FindElementByClass` throws a runtime error. Both functions find elements even if they have more than one class (in your example `attachmentText` and  `cuttapePara`.
I also prefer to write the result into intermediate variables before extracting the text. That helps to debug code and IMHO makes it more readable.

```
        Dim pkElems As WebElements
        Set pkElems = ProductRow.FindElementsByClass("cuttapePara")
        If pkElems.Count > 0 Then
            Prod_Pkg = pkElems(1).Text
        Else
            Prod_Pkg = "(not found)"
        End If
```

Comment: I see. I thought I had to use both class names when there were two. And with two class names `FindElementsByClass` would throw an error. I'll try it soon.. thank you