# Selenium VBA Get Parent Webelement of a Child WebElement

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

Let's say, when I have found a web element like the one by the line below:

```
Set ProductVariable = ProductRow.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='classname1 classname2']")"
```

How do I reference the Parent WebElement of `ProductVariable`?

(I am essentially after siblings of the original webelement, that I can't grab for whatever reason.)

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Syntax to construct XPath expression to locate the parent element of current node:

```
//tagname[@attribute='value']//parent::parentTagName
```

As per above syntax, change your XPath expression as below:

```
//*[@class='classname1 classname2']//parent::<parent tag>
```

**2.** Syntax to locate following-sibling element of current element:

```
//tagname[@attribute='value']//following-sibling::tagname
```

**3.** Syntax to locate preceding-sibling element of current element:

```
//tagname[@attribute='value']//preceding-sibling::tagname
```

Comment: My problem is fixed now. I still don't know why the code behaved the way it did. For reference this was my original problem: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77473540/seleniumbasic-vba-webscrape-findelementbyxpath-grabs-class-from-the-wrong-tr-bl`, which at the end didn't need to use `parent`. Having said that all the details you collected will definitely be useful for someone. I would tick both answer if I could, hence I won't do either. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest expression to get parent is

```vb
ProductRow.FindElementByXPath("..")
```

where `..` represents parent of current node.

Also can be done by JSExecutor by getting `parentElement` property.

```vb
Dim jsExecutor As IJavaScriptExecutor = CType(driver, IJavaScriptExecutor)
Dim result As Object = jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].parentElement;", ProductRow)
```

Comment: My problem is fixed now. I still don't know why the code behaved the way it did. For reference this was my original problem: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77473540/seleniumbasic-vba-webscrape-findelementbyxpath-grabs-class-from-the-wrong-tr-bl`, which at the end didn't need to use `parent`. Having said that, your solution will definitely be useful for someone. I love the simplicity of it. I would tick both answer if I could, hence I won't do either. Thank you very much for your help.